# Structure with 3 DIVs

Tags: css, html

How to accomplish the following structure?

[image: structure example]

This is what I got so far:

```
<style>
div{
    border: 1px solid;
}
#d1{
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}
#d2{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
}
#d3{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>

<div id="d1">
1
</div>
<div id="d2">
2
</div>
<div id="d3">
3
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not this experienced with CSS. Could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `absolute` positioning along with setting `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` as needed like so:

**CSS**

```css
#d1, #d2, #d3  {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    position: absolute;
}
#d1 {
    top: 0;
    height: 150px;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
#d2 {
    top: 150px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
#d3 {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 200px;
    right: 0;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g7Dtz/)**

Comment: Is it possible, to put all divs into one big div? So that I can move the whole thing around.

Comment: Yes, just make sure in the parent div you declare it's `position` otherwise  the children divs will not be positioned relative to the parent. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/g7Dtz/2/

Answer (score 1):

If you can change sequence of elements, you can do:

```
  * { line-height:16px; } 
  #i1 { margin:0 0 0 200px; background-color:#eef; }
  #i2 { margin-top:-16px; width:200px; height:150px; background-color:#efe; }
  #i3 { width:200px; background-color:#fee;}

  <div id="i1">main right</div>
  <div id="i2">left top</div>
  <div id="i3">left bottom</div>
```

But obviously it will be easier if you just wrap up your left column into one more div

```
  <div id="left">
     <div id="i2">left top</div>
     <div id="i3">left bottom</div>
 </div>
 <div id="main">main</div>


 #left {float:left; width:200px; margin:0;padding:0;}
 #main {margin-left:200px; }
 #i2 { width:200px; height:150px; }
 #i3 { width:200px; }
```

UPDATE: talking about 100% height and width; you also can use absolute positioning. [Here is example](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZArP/show/)

Comment: Thanks. But what about the 100% height and with?

Comment: Take a look at update. And also a question, what if bottom left part have more content then size of the screen ? what should happen ?